# Semi-Tricky SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query for SQL Server 2005 but I can't figure out how to do it.  I have a table with the following fields:

**MessageID int

CategoryID int

Priority tinyint

MessageText NVARCHAR(MAX)**

I need a query that will return * for each row that has the highest priority within a Category.  For example, if I had the following data:

**MessageID, CategoryID, Priority, MessageText**
1, 100, 1, Error #1234 occurred
2, 100, 2, Error #243 occurred
3, 100, 3, Error #976 occurred
4, 200, 4, Error #194 occurred
5, 200, 1, Error #736 occurred
6, 300, 3, Error #54 occurred
7, 300, 2, Error #888 occurred

then the result would be:

**MessageID, CategoryID, Priority, MessageText**
3, 100, 3, Error #976 occurred
4, 200, 4, Error #194 occurred
6, 300, 3, Error #54 occurred

Notice that it returns one row per category, and that it is the row which had the highest priority for that Category.

Can anyone tell me how I can write this query?

Comment: You could write it far easier using analytical functions in Oracle.  :)

Comment: Or using the analytical functions in SQL Server and not have to port to Oracle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verified:

```
SELECT
    highest_priority_messages.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
    m.MessageID
    , m.CategoryID
    , m.Priority
    , m.MessageText
    , Rank() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY m.CategoryID ORDER BY m.Priority DESC) AS p_rank
    FROM [Message] m
    GROUP BY 
        m.CategoryID 
        , m.Priority
        , m.MessageID
        , m.MessageText
) highest_priority_messages
WHERE 
    p_rank = 1
```

Comment: You will also want to add a CreatedDate and figure that into the equation for ordering I'm sure.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a way to use PARTITION here without using Rank()?

Comment: You could do MAX(m.Priority) OVER (PARTITION BY m.CategoryID) AS MaxPriority, but then the WHERE would have to compare the Priority to the MaxPriority.  It also depends on whether you want multiples of the top priority or not.

Comment: What's the use of `GROUP BY` here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this should work, table name assumed as Messages

```
SELECT
    M.MessageId,
    M.CategoryId,
    M.Priority,
    M.MessageText
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        CategoryId,
        MAX(Priority) AS Priority
    FROM Messages
    GROUP BY CategoryId
) AS MaxValues
    INNER JOIN Messages M
        ON (MaxValues.CategoryId = M.CategoryId
                AND MaxValues.Priority = M.Priority)
```

**NOTE**

The only "gotcha" in this method is that if you have more than one max priority...

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to do it without all of the subqueries:

```
SELECT
     MessageID,
     CategoryID,
     Priority,
     MessageText
FROM
     dbo.Messages M1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Messages M2 ON
     M2.CategoryID = M1.CategoryID AND
     M2.Priority > M1.Priority
WHERE
     M2.MessageID IS NULL
```

You might have to adjust the query depending on how you want to handle ties. You didn't have any such examples, so I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct query1.* from

(select categoryId,msgText,max(priorityId) as MAX_PRIORITY
 from message
  group by categoryId,msgText
 order by categoryId
) query1,


(select categoryId,max(priorityId) as MAX_PRIORITY
 from message
  group by categoryId
 order by categoryId
) query2

where query1.MAX_PRIORITY = query2.MAX_PRIORITY

order by query1.categoryId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Messages.MessageID
    , Messages.CategoryID
    , Messages.Priority
    , Messages. MessageText
FROM
    Messages
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            CategoryID
            , MAX(Priority) AS Priority
        FROM 
            Messages
        GROUP BY
            CategoryID
    ) AS MaxResults
    ON
        (
            Messages.CategoryID = MaxResults.CategoryID
            AND
            Messages.Priority = MaxResults.Priority
        )
```

It looks like this is basically the same answer given above... with the same Caveat.

Although this one will work right off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

This is shorter and easier to read (imo).

```
select ms.*
from 
  messages ms
 ,(
  select ms1.categoryid, max(ms1.priority) as max_priority
  from messages ms1
  group by ms1.categoryid
  ) tmp
where ms.categoryid = tmp.categoryid
  and ms.priority = tmp.max_priority;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite high enough rank (yet) to post a comment, so I'd like to add to cfeduke's solution:

```
SELECT
    highest_priority_messages.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
    m.MessageID
    , m.CategoryID
    , m.Priority
    , m.MessageText
    , Rank() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY m.CategoryID ORDER BY m.Priority DESC, m.MessageID DESC) AS p_rank
    FROM [Message] m
    GROUP BY 
        m.CategoryID 
        , m.Priority
        , m.MessageID
        , m.MessageText
) highest_priority_messages
WHERE 
    p_rank = 1
```

If you add another CategoryID 100 Message with Priority 3, the original solution would bring back 2 rows, by adding another order condition we eliminate the chance of two items ranking the same.

Here's a copy of the row I inserted to test this.

```
insert into [Message] (MessageID, CategoryID, Priority, MessageText)
select 8, 100, 3, 'Error #976-2 occurred'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CategoryId,PS.Priority,MessageID,MessageText
FROM Priority_Scene PS
JOIN (SELECT MAX(Priority) AS Priority FROM Priority_Scene GROUP BY CategoryId) A
ON A.Priority   = PS.Priority
```

Comment: If same category has two priorities on the same and highest level then also it will work